# Cannot access script by ID on HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to programmatically access the script which is written in `<script>..</script>` but the using the id assigned to the script is not working.

I think the problem in my html form.

Please help me; I want to access `from date`, `to date`, & `reminder date`, the `all` operation depends on the `from date`.

Here is my code:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700);
 body {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}
div,
textarea,
input {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  max-width: 510px;
  min-width: 324px;
  margin: 50px auto 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  padding: 0 2.5em;
}
.row.header {
  padding: 1.5em 2.5em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: url(http://niiiick.com/files/blur-city-1.jpg) left -80px;
  color: #fff;
}
.row.body {
  padding: .5em 2.5em 1em;
}
.pull-right {
  float: right;
}
h1 {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 2.8125em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  margin: 0 0 0.1em 0;
  padding: 0 0 0.4em 0;
}
h3 {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  margin: 1em 0 0.4em 0;
}
.btn {
  font-size: 1.0625em;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.74em 1.5em;
  margin: 1.5em 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  border-width: 0 0 0 0;
  border-bottom: 5px solid;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
  border-bottom-color: #8c8c8c;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.btn:hover {
  background-color: #bfbfbf;
}
.btn.btn-submit {
  background-color: #4f6fad;
  border-bottom-color: #374d78;
}
.btn.btn-submit:hover {
  background-color: #5f7db6;
}
form {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
form ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
form ul li {
  margin: 0 0 0.25em 0;
  clear: both;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
form ul li:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}
form ul li p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}
form ul li p.right {
  float: right;
}
form ul li .divider {
  margin: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: #4f6fad;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ee9cb4, #4f6fad);
}
form ul li .req {
  color: #ee9cb4;
}
form label {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
  color: #4f6fad;
  font-size: 1em;
}
form input {
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 1em;
}
form textarea {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #555;
}
form small {
  color: #4f6fad;
  margin: 0 0 0 0.5em;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .pull-right {
    float: none;
  }
  input {
    width: 100%;
  }
  label {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
  }
  li,
  p {
    width: 100%;
  }
  input.btn {
    margin: 1.5em 0 0.5em;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 2.25em;
  }
  h3 {
    font-size: 1.125em;
  }
  li small {
    display: none;
  }
}
/*! normalize.css v4.0.0 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%
}
body {
  margin: 0
}
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
main,
menu,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block
}
audio,
canvas,
progress,
video {
  display: inline-block
}
audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
  height: 0
}
progress {
  vertical-align: baseline
}
template,
[hidden] {
  display: none
}
a {
  background-color: transparent
}
a:active,
a:hover {
  outline-width: 0
}
abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration: underline dotted
}
b,
strong {
  font-weight: inherit
}
b,
strong {
  font-weight: bolder
}
dfn {
  font-style: italic
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0.67em 0
}
mark {
  background-color: #ff0;
  color: #000
}
small {
  font-size: 80%
}
sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline
}
sub {
  bottom: -0.25em
}
sup {
  top: -0.5em
}
img {
  border-style: none
}
svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden
}
code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, monospace;
  font-size: 1em
}
figure {
  margin: 1em 40px
}
hr {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0;
  overflow: visible
}
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0
}
optgroup {
  font-weight: bold
}
button,
input,
select {
  overflow: visible
}
button,
select {
  text-transform: none
}
button,
[type="button"],
[type="reset"],
[type="submit"] {
  cursor: pointer
}
[disabled] {
  cursor: default
}
button,
html [type="button"],
[type="reset"],
[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button
}
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0
}
button:-moz-focusring,
input:-moz-focusring {
  outline: 1px dotted ButtonText
}
fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em
}
legend {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: inherit;
  display: table;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: normal
}
textarea {
  overflow: auto
}
[type="checkbox"],
[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0
}
[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto
}
[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield
}
[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Clean Contact Form</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalizeindex.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styleindex.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row header">
      <center>
        <h1>WELCOME &nbsp;</h1>
      </center>
    </div>
    <div class="row body">
      <form method="post">
        <ul>

          <li>
            <p class="left">
              <label for="member_id">MEMBERS No.:</label>
              <input type="text" name="" />
            </p>
            <p class="pull-right">
              <label for="mem_date">MEMBERSHIP DATE:</label>
              <input type="date" name="" />
            </p>
          </li>

          <li>
            <div class="divider"></div>
          </li>

          <li>
            <p class="left">
              <label for="from">FROM:</label>
              <input type="date" id="oldDate">
            </p>
            <p class="pull-right">
              <label for="to">TO:</label>
              <input type="date" id="new">
            </p>
            <p class="left">
              <label for="name">REMINDER DATE:</label>
              <input type="date" id="reminde">
            </p>
          </li>
          <script>
            // <---Next Renewal Date--->    
            $('#oldDate').on('change', function(e) {
              var oldDate = new Date(this.value);
              $('#old').html(new Date(oldDate));
              oldDate.setFullYear(oldDate.getFullYear() + 1);
              oldDate.setDate(oldDate.getDate());

              var day = ("0" + oldDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
              var month = ("0" + (oldDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

              var today = oldDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (month) + "-" + (day);

              $('#new').val(today);
              // <---End Renwal Date--->        

              // <---Start Reminder date--->       
              $('#old').html(new Date(oldDate));
              oldDate.setFullYear(oldDate.getFullYear());
              oldDate.setDate(oldDate.getDate() - 15);

              var day = ("0" + oldDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
              var month = ("0" + (oldDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

              var today = oldDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (month) + "-" + (day);

              $('#reminde').val(today);
              // <---End Reminder Date--->  
            });
          </script>

          <li>
            <div class="divider"></div>
          </li>

          <li>
            <p class="left">
              <label for="name">MEMBER NAME:</label>
              <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter the name.." />
            </p>
            <p class="pull-right">
              <label for="mob_no">MOBILE NO.:</label>
              <input type="number" name="" />
            </p>
            <br>
            <p class="left">
              <br>
              <label for="mem_name">FAMILY MEMBER NAME:</label>
              <input type="text" name="" />
            </p>
            <p class="pull-right">
              <br>
              <label for="mem_no">FAMILY MEMBER NO.:</label>
              <input type="number" name="" />
            </p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="divider"></div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <center>
              <input class="btn btn-submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </center>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>





</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Place your script inside `$(document).ready(function(){ //Your code goes here...  });`

Comment: Also please place the script inside `<head>` tag or at the bottom, just before `</body>`  tag ends.

Comment: Double doctype. That's new.

Comment: you can refer this jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/3tw1xLy0/

Answer (score 0):

This is your formatted code. And there is one more error is there in your code. You have not loaded Jquery, but you are accessing the jquery method when it is loaded. There for, please load Jquery. Below is the syntax.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Your formatted code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Clean Contact Form</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalizeindex.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styleindex.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row header">
        <center>
            <h1>WELCOME &nbsp;</h1>
        </center>

    </div>
    <div class="row body">
        <form method="post">
            <ul>

                <li>
                    <p class="left">
                        <label for="member_id">MEMBERS No.:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="" />
                    </p>
                    <p class="pull-right">
                        <label for="mem_date">MEMBERSHIP DATE:</label>
                        <input type="date" name="" />
                    </p>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <div class="divider"></div>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <p class="left">
                        <label for="from">FROM:</label>
                        <input type="date" id="oldDate">
                    </p>
                    <p class="pull-right">
                        <label for="to">TO:</label>
                        <input type="date" id="new">
                    </p>
                    <p class="left">
                        <label for="name">REMINDER DATE:</label>
                        <input type="date" id="reminde">
                    </p>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <div class="divider"></div>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <p class="left">
                        <label for="name">MEMBER NAME:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter the name.." />
                    </p>
                    <p class="pull-right">
                        <label for="mob_no">MOBILE NO.:</label>
                        <input type="number" name="" />
                    </p>
                    <br>
                    <p class="left">
                        <br>
                        <label for="mem_name">FAMILY MEMBER NAME:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="" />
                    </p>
                    <p class="pull-right">
                        <br>
                        <label for="mem_no">FAMILY MEMBER NO.:</label>
                        <input type="number" name="" />
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="divider"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <center>
                        <input class="btn btn-submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </center>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

// <---Next Renewal Date--->    
$('#oldDate').on('change', function(e) {
    var oldDate = new Date(this.value);
    $('#old').html(new Date(oldDate));
    oldDate.setFullYear(oldDate.getFullYear() + 1);
    oldDate.setDate(oldDate.getDate());

    var day = ("0" + oldDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ("0" + (oldDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

    var today = oldDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (month) + "-" + (day);

    $('#new').val(today);
    // <---End Renwal Date--->        

    // <---Start Reminder date--->       
    $('#old').html(new Date(oldDate));
    oldDate.setFullYear(oldDate.getFullYear());
    oldDate.setDate(oldDate.getDate() - 15);

    var day = ("0" + oldDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ("0" + (oldDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

    var today = oldDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (month) + "-" + (day);

    $('#reminde').val(today);
    // <---End Reminder Date--->  
    });

 });

</script>
  </body>
 </html>
```